# Reactjs : I have to refresh Login component to redirect authenticated users to dashboard

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, browser-history

I am trying to set up a user authentication system in my react-redux application. on login, user is authenticated successfully, however, user is stuck in the login page after the first click and only goes to dashboard after page refresh.

```
//Login

  componentDidMount() {
    
    // If logged in and user navigates to Login page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      history.push("/c/dashboard");
    }     
  }
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
   
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log("auth",nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) // returns isAuthenticated as true
      history.push("/c/dashboard"); // push user to dashboard when they login
    }
if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    this.props.loginUser(userData); 
  };
```

App.js

```
render(){
   
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
     
         <Switch>
           <Route  path="/c">
             <LoggedInComponent /> // here is were you have the dashboard component
           </Route>
          
           <Route  path="/s">
             <LoggedOutComponent />  //here is were you have the login component    
           </Route>  
          
         </Switch>
       
   </BrowserRouter>
   </Provider>
```

How can i redirect user to dashboard ,after the first click of the login button.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example through e.g. Codepen

Comment: ok let me do that ...